# Django: Best practice for showing list of Models (as a text) based on group permissions given to specific user

Tags: django

My main concern is to show a list of Models that user can interact with based on given permissions.

I am thinking of doing this by way of user's group permissions. I wanna mimic how the `Django admin` is able to list the models when you give any permissions to the user related to that model like this:
[image]

For example I have model called `Posts` with permissions `can_add_post` and `can_delete_post`. I am assigned to a Group called `Writer` that has been assigned with both permissions. In my view, I want to be able to retrieve the name of `'Posts'` model *as a text* so I can do something with it like set an `onClick` function to call a respective React component like this:

[image]

I have no clear business logic in mind to do this though. However, I am using DRF and I have a Login API and I'm thinking I might put the logic inside this API so that I can fetch all permissions of this logged in user and show those modules that he has access on.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my Login API View:

```
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
serializer_class = LoginSerializer
permission_classes = ()

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.validated_data
    return Response(
        {
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1],
            "authenticated": True
        }
    )
```

Comment: `In my view, I want to be able to retrieve the name of 'Posts' model as a text ©` retrieve from where? Show your view code?

Comment: I am actually using DRF so I am implementing the APIs for views. I dont have my laptop with me atm but I'll update above with my Login API class (extended from generics.GenericAPIView) soon as I can. I have not written any logic yet since I have no idea where to start for now. I might need to ask some insights on how I might be able to do that. I simply just want to list down models that are related to permissions given to the logged in user just how Django Admin does when it lists down models and you can do add/change capabilities on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

#for user permisions
set(Permission.objects.filter(user=your_user).values_list('content_type__model', flat = True))
#for user groups permisions
set(Permission.objects.filter(group__user=your_user).values_list('content_type__model', flat = True))
```

This is concept, so you should adapt it to your needs

p.s.: using `set()` because i don't know how to `distinct()` on `content_type__model` field, perhaps a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see the codes above show the name of the app where those permissions live in. That is great. But my primary concern is to show the model name instead of the app name... Thanks

Comment: After looking at the docs and using your concept above, found the answer with 'content_type__model'. Thanks a lot...